# Mudar de cor de uma Row quando expirar VB .Net

Tags: .net, data, gridview, visual-basic-6

Tenho uma base de dados com as seguintes tabelas: `Data Emissão` e `Data Expira`.

Então eu quero que, quando a data do `Data expira` for igual ou superior a `Data Emissao`, a `row` mude de cor para `Vermelho` e quando estiver faltando 1 mês para atingir a data mude de cor para `Amarelo`.

---

**Meus codigos**

```
Private Sub CadastroDataGridView_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles CadastroDataGridView.CellFormatting
    If Me.CadastroDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn15" Then
        If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dgvdate As Date = CDate(e.Value)
            If dgvdate < CDate(Now) Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                e.FormattingApplied = True
            Else
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
                e.FormattingApplied = True
            End If

        End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Com as seguintes colunas não tabelas, certo?

Comment: Poste as Tabelas completas...

Comment: Por favor, mostre o seu código, saliente o que importa para a dúvida e diga o que já tentou.

Answer (score 2):

Não testei, mas deve funcionar:

```
Dim data_addmes As Date = Date.Now.AddMonth(1)
Dim data_expira As Date = dgvRow.Cells("Data_expira").Value
Dim data_emissa As Data = dgvRow.Cells("Data_Emissao").Value

If data_addmes >= data_expira Then
    dgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
Else If data_expira >= data_expira Then
   dgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

Comment: Poste seu código que poderei melhorar minha resposta